# Convert a doubly linked list into balanced binary search tree in-place

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, tree

> Given a doubly linked list which has data members sorted in ascending
>   order, construct a balanced binary search tree which has same data
>   members as the given doubly linked list. The tree must be constructed
>   in-place (no new node should be allocated for tree conversion).

This question is attributed to Geeksforgeeks.  I'm looking for code review, optimizations and best practices.

```
class Node<T> {
    Node<T> left;
    T item;
    Node<T> right;

    Node(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

class LinkedLists<T> {
    private Node<T> first;
    private Node<T> last;
    private int size = 0;

    public LinkedLists(List<T> items) {
        for (T item : items) {
            add(item);
        }
    }

    private void add(T item) {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(item);
        if (first == null) {
            first = last = node;
        } else {
            last.right = node;
            node.left = last;
            last = node;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public Node<T> getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}


class BinaryTree<T> {

    private Node<T> root;

    public BinaryTree(Node<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public BinaryTree(List<T> items) {
        create(items);
    }

    private void create (List<? extends T> items) {
        root = new Node<T>(items.get(0));

        final Queue<Node<T>> queue = new LinkedList<Node<T>>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final Node<T> current = queue.poll();                
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new Node<T>(items.get(left));
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new Node<T>(items.get(right));
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCompute(root, 0);
    }

    public int hashCompute (Node<T> node, int item) {
        if (node == null) return item;
        item = 31 * hashCompute (node.left, item) + node.hashCode();
        return hashCompute(node.right, item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        BinaryTree<T> other = (BinaryTree<T>) obj;
        return equal(root, other.root);
    }


    private boolean equal(Node<T> node1, Node<T> node2) {
        if (node1 == null && node2 == null) return true;
        if (node1 == null || node2 == null) return false;
        if (node1.item != node2.item) {
            return false;
        }

        return equal(node1.left, node2.left) && equal(node1.right, node2.right);
    }
}



/**
 * 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874517/converting-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list-to-a-bst
 * 
 * Complexity is O(n), since in each recursion, one node of DLL is taken care of.
 * 
 */
public final class DLLtoBinaryTree {

    private DLLtoBinaryTree() {}

    public static <T> Node<T> convert(LinkedLists<T> list)  {
        return convert(new NodeStore<T>(list.getFirst()), list.size()); 
    }

    /**
     * Used as a mechanism to preserve the changes made in recursion tree.
     * The changes made down the tree, should be preserved when that stack frame is popped.
     */
    private static class NodeStore<T> {
        private Node<T> node = null;
        NodeStore (Node<T> newNode) {
            this.node = newNode;
        }
    }


    private static <T> Node<T> convert(NodeStore<T> ns, int n) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            return null;
        } 

        final Node<T> left = convert(ns, n/2);

        final Node<T> currNode = ns.node;
        ns.node = ns.node.right;

        currNode.left = left; 
        currNode.right = convert(ns, n - n/2 - 1);

        return currNode;
    }
}



public class DLLtoBinaryTreeTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        LinkedLists<Integer> list1 = new LinkedLists<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
        Node<Integer> root1 = DLLtoBinaryTree.convert(list1); 

        BinaryTree<Integer> bstExpected1 = new BinaryTree<>(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7));
        BinaryTree<Integer> bstActual1 = new BinaryTree<>(root1);

        assertEquals(bstExpected1, bstActual1); 
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        LinkedLists<Integer> list2 = new LinkedLists<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        Node<Integer> root2 = DLLtoBinaryTree.convert(list2); 

        BinaryTree<Integer> bstExpected2 = new BinaryTree<>(Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3));
        BinaryTree<Integer> bstActual2 = new BinaryTree<>(root2);

        assertEquals(bstExpected2, bstActual2); 
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        LinkedLists<Integer> list3 = new LinkedLists<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        Node<Integer> root3 = DLLtoBinaryTree.convert(list3); 

        BinaryTree<Integer> bstExpected3 = new BinaryTree<>(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 4, 1));
        BinaryTree<Integer> bstActual3 = new BinaryTree<>(root3);

        assertEquals(bstExpected3, bstActual3); 
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        LinkedLists<Integer> list4 = new LinkedLists<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
        Node<Integer> root4 = DLLtoBinaryTree.convert(list4); 

        BinaryTree<Integer> bstExpected4 = new BinaryTree<>(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5));
        BinaryTree<Integer> bstActual4 = new BinaryTree<>(root4);

        assertEquals(bstExpected4, bstActual4); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Duplicated answer from here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63125/49350)

Bug:

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` on empty list in `BinaryTree.create(List<? extends T> items)`. You don't have a comment stating you need to input a list containing at least something. Consider returning `IllegalArgumentException` and adding a comment.

---

You also have a space between a function call and its arguments here:

```
item = 31 * hashCompute (node.left, item) + node.hashCode();
```